# Repeatable build for Lambda Layers in monorepo with Yarn Workspaces

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda, yarn-workspaces, aws-lambda-layers

I have pretty big monorepo, managed solely by [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) (no Lerna). One of the packages ("workspaces") contains a set of 3rd party NodeJS packages that we use as a [shared layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for our Lambda functions, collected as `dependencies` in `package.json` of this package. Build script for this package is supposed to collect all dependencies in a zip file that will be later published by Terraform. Unfortunately, Yarn cannot build *single* workspace from the monorepo, so we have to use NPM directly.

Currently we do roughly the following -

1. copy `package.json` to a `build` folder
2. run `npm install --production` in this folder
3. zip the resulting `node_modules` tree

My main problem with this approach (besides mixing the build tools) is that the build is not repeatable - each time we run `npm install` we may get newer compatible version of any dependent package, since the version is "locked" by Yarn in the top-level `yarn.lock` file and NPM (obviously) is not aware about it.

I'm pretty sure we are not alone in this boat. Are there any better approaches available?

Comment: Or you can keep the hoisting feature and build your function with webpack, I don't understand why you are zipping the node_modules?

Comment: @ZEE With webpack you get a big chunk of JS code, which is hardly readable. It is super-convenient to preserve the code and the code structure to be able to log into Lambda console and add a log statement, since your code in the real deployment behaves differently than in your unit tests.

Comment: The source map is there for that.

Comment: I don't think code editor in the AWS Lambda console supports source maps - unless it had changed relatively recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that while Yarn *hoists* all the dependencies to the `node_modules` of the top-level workspace, [you can explicitly **opt-out** from this behavior](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/) for some dependencies - or, in my case, for **all** dependencies of the given workspace.

Yarn Workspaces configuration before:

```
"workspaces": [
  "packages/*"
]
```

Yarn Workspaces configuration after the change, assuming Lambda Layer dependencies are collected under `common-lambda` workspace:

```
"workspaces": {
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "nohoist": [
    "common-lambda/**"
  ]
}
```

After this change `packages/common-lambda/node_modules` will contain proper versions of all the dependencies to be packaged as Lambda Layer.

Note that `nohoist` array should contain workspace *name* (including namespace where applicable) and not workspace folder.